# Paper of Denis Simon on quadratic equations in dimensions 4, 5?

Tags: reference-request, algorithms, quadratic-forms, integral-quadratic-forms

In several places I have come across references to a 2005-6 preprint of Denis Simon entitled

*Quadratic equations in dimensions 4, 5, and more*

This paper gives fast algorithms to find isotropic vectors in a 4 or 5 dimensional quadratic space over $\mathbb{Q}$, based on indefinite LLL.

I have been unable to get a hold of it. Is it online? Has it been published?

Comment: It seems to have been presented at a talk with the title [Recent Developments in Computational Number Theory](http://poncelet.sciences.univ-metz.fr/~soriano/ProgrammeCIRM.pdf) on May 20, 2005.

Comment: Perhaps the best way would be to e-mail [the author](http://www.math.unicaen.fr/~simon/).

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche - I've tried that but haven't heard back. (Maybe I still will...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It used to be on Simon's website, and [archive.org](https://archive.org/web/) saved a copy:

http://web.archive.org/web/20061123185700/http://math.unicaen.fr/~simon/maths/Dim4.pdf

Thanks to Mark Watkins for pointing this out.

I have reached out to Simon to ask about it but haven't heard back, so I don't know an explanation for why he took it down.

Answer (score 1):

It's available here: http://www.researchgate.net/publication/228523875_Quadratic_equations_in_dimensions_4_5_and_more

Click "view" on the upper right to read the paper.  (I don't know if you can download it, though.)

Comment: It seems just to be the first 5 pages, and the "external download" link is broken, but thank you!